# Python: Printing brackets around statements (class objects) based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, oop

Just a heads up, this isn't homework, it's from a past paper i'm trying to do but we have no reference to how to 'actually' do it.

We've been given a task to implement '+' alongside 'Const' as set of classes, with the idea of working out whether to place brackets around the expression or not - for example:

eg1. Plus(Plus(Const(3),Const(4)),Const(5)) should print 3 + 4 + 5

eg2. Plus(Const(3),Plus(Const(4),Const(5))) should print 3 + (4 + 5)

So, I've come to the conclusion that I need something within my **str** method which checks if there is more than one 'value' in my self.l or self.r, and if so to print brackets around the self.l or self.r respectively. I believe this to be the case because in eg2, there is a 'plus' which applies to more than one constant. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I'm not looking for someone to give me the answer to this, but more of a hint of where to begin. I've recently began coding and am finding it difficult to be able to work out how to implement what I want to do.

```
class Expr :
    pass


class Plus(Expr) :
    def __init__(self,l,r) :
        self.l = l
        self.r = r


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.l)+ "+" +str(self.r) #I believe here is where I need to implement.

class Const(Expr) :
    def __init__(self,v) :
        self.v = v

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.v)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

My Lecturer gave the answer, but i'm a little confused by the 'par' meaning - could anyone help me comprehend why bool values are used to differentiate?

```
class Expr :
    def __str__(self) :
        return self.str_aux(False)

class Plus(Expr) :
    def str_aux(self,par) :
        s =self.l.str_aux(False)+"+"+self.r.str_aux(True)
        if par :
            return "("+s+")"
        else :
            return s

class Const(Expr) :
    def __init__(self,v) :
        self.v = v

    def str_aux(self,par) :
        return str(self.v)
```

Comment: It looks like you're assuming that `Plus` is a left-associative operation.  You might find this Wikipedia section helpful: [Notation for non-associative operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Notation_for_non-associative_operations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is fairly straightforward: if the right hand side of a `Plus` is itself a `Plus`, then you want to add parentheses, otherwise you don't.

As for checking if `self.l` and `self.r` exist, you should use `isinstance` to differentiate between a `Plus` and a `Const`.

```
class Plus(Expr) :
    def __init__(self,l,r) :
        self.l = l
        self.r = r

    def __str__(self):
        if isinstance(self.r, Plus):
            return '{} + ({})'.format(self.l, self.r)
        else:
            return '{} + {}'.format(self.l, self.r)
```

### Example

```
print(Plus(Const(3),Plus(Const(4),Const(5))))
print(Plus(Plus(Const(3),Const(4)),Const(5)))
```

### Output

```
3 + (4 + 5)
3 + 4 + 5
```

## About your lecturer solution

Your lecturer implemented the same solution as above but delegates the task to add parenthesis to the object being printed.

The method `str_aux` behaves similarly to `__str__` except it also takes a boolean argument `par` that indicates whether or not parentheses should be printed.

#### Example

```
plus = Plus(Const(3), Const(4))
plus.str_aux(False) # "3+4"
plus.str_aux(True) # "(3+4)"
```

The base case is when printing a `Const` which `str_aux` ignores the `par` and does not print parentheses.

Comment: This is brilliant, but I should have specified that I cant use 'isinstance()' in this. Is there a way of doing so without?

Comment: @philcode101 why can't you use isinstance? This is exactly what it should be used for.

Comment: because the exam I take is a beginners programming module where we can only use 'what we have learn'. We did a similar exercise but instead using logical operators (And, Or, Not, Equiv etc..) and I worked out how to establish a 'precedence' between operators and when to assign brackets and when not, but i'm unable to do it with this instance. It's stupid I know.

Comment: @philcode101 I think you should give up that module since anything that asks you to implement classes and inheritance before teaching you what isinstance is for is kind of doing things upside down. This is the cleanest way to do this and trying to artificially come up with anything else is coutner productive to your learning process.

Comment: I'm a Philosophy graduate now taking an MSc in CS, this is a conversion course as I want to go into Ethical AI. I understand where you are coming from and I believe it's counter-intuitive too, but it's how it is and it's a reputable university so they're clearly doing something right. I think a lot of the focus is about 'making us think that way' which is why they are avoiding allowing us to use inbuilt functions.

Comment: @philcode101 Let me try to get a work around that would make sense for you

Comment: Thanks Olivier, here is an exert of how I worked it out with logical operators if it helps : https://gist.github.com/OwennB/1f34bbbd9d462e19dfde81519345d3b5

Comment: @philcode101 I suggest you had that example in the question since using the precedence attribute will allow us to define a more general and robust rule using something else than isinstance

Comment: I agree, I was thinking it would be relative and work similarly but it doesnt seem to be the case unfortunately. Oh well.

Comment: My teacher uploaded the solution and it's really biarre - was wondering if you could help with it - I have uploaded it underneath the question as a block of code.

Comment: @philcode101 sure thing, i will when i come back from work. Feel free to pingouin me if i forget

Comment: @philcode101 I added some explanations about your lecturer's solution